# Weird behavior when new operator inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
    var coin = new Coin(mStage , { x : 0 , y : 0 });
    coin.id = i;
    mAvailableCoins.push(coin);
  }
```

Is behaving weirdly. I tried to watch the variables for mAvailableCoins[0] - [3] and saw that it is not actually being pushed at all. What is being pushed is a single instance of Coin, the first one I created. This is noticeable with the ID i set.

When I set mAvailableCoins[0] its id is 0. Next pushing the newly created coin into the array set the id mAvailableCoins[1].id is 1. Which is expected. I inspect mAvailableCoins[0] nad its id is also 1.

I run this on different for loop of my code and it works there. it just fails right here. Here is the sample of my that works, though this is placed on a different file/scope/method etc.

```
  var coins = world.borrowCoins(mLength , heightCount);
  var i = 0;

  for(var x = 0; x < mLength; ++x)
  {
    for(var y = 0; y < heightCount; ++y)
    {
      //var coin = coins[i];
      var coin = new Coin(mStage , {x : 0 , y : 0});
      coin.x   = mPosition.x + (x * world.blockSize);
      coin.y   = ChunkGroup.pixelHeight - ((y + 1) * world.blockSize);
      coin.id = i;

      world.addInhabitant(coin);
      mStage.addChild(coin.sprite);

      console.log("Coin id : " + coin.id + " position (" + x + " , " + y + ") pos : " + coin.x + " , " + coin.y); 

      i++;
    }
  }
```

[EDIT]
Here is my Coin.js, this is a subclass of Inhabitant:

```
define(["src/Inhabitant"], function(Inhabitant)
{
  console.log("Coin.js loaded");

  return (function(stage)
  {
    var mRunSpeed = 0;
    var id = 0;

    function Coin(stage)
    {
      Inhabitant.call(this, stage, 'coinGold.png');
    }

    Coin.prototype = Object.create(Inhabitant.prototype);

    Coin.prototype.update = function(elapsed)
    {
      Inhabitant.prototype.x -= mRunSpeed * elapsed;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(Coin, 'runSpeed', 
      {
          get : function(){ return mRunSpeed; }
        , set : function(speed){ mRunSpeed = speed; }
      });

    Object.defineProperty(Coin, 'id', 
      {
        get : function(){ return mRunSpeed; }
      , set : function(speed){ mRunSpeed = speed; }
      });

    return Coin;

  })();
});
```

So here its parent the Inhabitant.js:

```
define([], function()
{
  console.log("Inhabitant loaded.");

  var Inhabitant = (function()
    {
      var mStage  = null;
      var mSprite = null;
      var mID     = -1;

      function Inhabitant(stage, resource)
      {
        mStage = stage;
        mSprite = new PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame(resource);
      }

      Inhabitant.prototype =
      {
          get sprite(){ return mSprite; }

        , set position(position){ mSprite.position = position; } , get position(){ return mSprite.position; }
        , get x(){ return mSprite.x; } , get y(){ return mSprite.y; }

        , set x(x){ mSprite.x = x; } 

        , set y(y){ mSprite.y = y; }

        , get id(){ return mID; } , set id(id){ mID = id; }

        , update : update
        , show   : show
      }

      function update(elapsed)
      {
        console.log("Update called from Inhabitant");
      }

      function show(show)
      {
        mSprite.visible = show;
      }

      return Inhabitant;

    })();

  return Inhabitant;
});
```

Here is World.js where the loop is invoked:

```
define(["src/Coin", "src/Block" , "src/ChunkGroup", "src/Chunk"] , function(Coin, Block , ChunkGroup, Chunk)
{
  console.log("World loaded.");

  return function(stage , position , viewportSize, screenSize , blockSize)
  {
    var onNewFloor = function(Chunk){};

    var mStage             = stage;
    ...
    var mInhabitants         = [];
    var mAvailableCoins      = [];
    ...

    var mOnBorderlineChangedListener = { newBorderline : 0 };

    ...

    function fillCoins(count)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      {
        var coin4 = new Coin(mStage);
        coin4.id = i;
        mAvailableCoins.push(coin4);
      }

      ...
    }

    function init(segmentCount, segmentLength)
    {
      ...
      showBackground();
      fillRampGroups(100);
      fillCoins(850);

      ...
    }

    return World;
  };

});
```

This is where World is initialized and calling its method World.init(...):

```
define(['src/Coin' , 'src/Runner2', 'src/World' , 'src/Chunk', 'src/ChunkGroup'] , function(Coin, Runner2, World, Chunk, ChunkGroup)
{
  console.log("MainGameScene loaded.");

  return function (renderer , screenSize)
  {
    var blockSize = 70;

    var mStage                     = new PIXI.Container();
    ...

    var mWorld = World(mStage, {x : 0 , y : 530}, {width : screenSize.width , height : screenSize.height} , mScreenSize , blockSize);
    mWorld.runSpeed = 350;
    mWorld.init(21, 7); // make sure that the length is odd number...
    ...

    var MainGameScene = {};

    ...

    return MainGameScene;
  }

});
```

This is mind boggling. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Well, we can't explain unless we have the code for your coin class. And is mAvailableCoins just an array? And what is mStage while we're at it?

Comment: this absolute minimum functional example does not behave as you suggest - http://jsfiddle.net/mc13x83x/

Comment: Please show the code for the `Coin` constructor.

Comment: Alright wait for my next edit. Don't worry about mStage, its a variable assigned with a third party library (Pixi.js), very irrelevant actually.

Comment: There you go, please see my new edit.

Comment: `mAvailableCoins` and `mStage` are never defined, as such we can't give a complete solution without knowing that.

Comment: The public symbol `Coin` use in the `loop is also not shown. Only the private one is defined.  And, there are mistakes in the Coin implementation which are likely separate from the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Its actually a huge code by now, I only pasted the most relevant ones. Well I could replicate this just running a simple loop. mAvailableCoins is declared as an array. you can ignore mStage since I am not storing coins there. Its related to showing sprites. Showing sprites is not my problem. My problem was, why in mAvailableCoins, the first instance of Coin was stored n times on that array. That's why I wonder why there are only 1 coin showing on the screen.

Comment: Try a simple test.  `var x = new Coin(...); var y = new Coin(...)`.   Then look at `x` and `y` and see if they are the same object.  If so (which is my guess), the problem is in your `Coin` constructor as it isn't creating new objects.

Comment: Sigh, I understand now, I am trying to put Prototypal inheritance in a Module Pattern, it will not bend on my will. I think I misunderstood some concept which led to this. You can post your answer, you are correct. My coin class was declared as such it will return the outer most function which will return to me my prototype object. There lies the problem. Every time i define() Coin, the variables on Coin.js is declared, but ONLY once and every instance is sharing it. It looks like it is acting like a static variable. Maybe I need to expose my class in different way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All instances of your Coin class are using (sharing) the same variables:

```
var mRunSpeed = 0;
var id = 0;
```

as they are in outer scope of your get/set functions. Change your code to this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Coin, 'id', 
      {
        get : function(){ return this._id; }
      , set : function(id){ this._id = id; }
      });
```

and you should see the difference.

Comment: This is exactly what I did! Though I stick to the prototypal inheritance instead of using Modular approach since this fits best in my situation.